# Sublime Text 2 image preview plugin

Tags: sublimetext2

Does anyone know of a plugin for Sublime Text 2 that allows you to preview images? I tend to use Sublime for everything now, but one thing that I miss about Coda is the ability to see pictures without having to leave the program.

Apologies if this has already been answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime Text 3 dev build 3055 realized with image preview when opening images.

You can download dev builds on the [official site](http://www.sublimetext.com/3dev).

Sublime Text 3 dev builds are currently available to registered users only.

Answer (score 0):

this one opens default image viewer 
[Sublime-Text-2-Image-Viewer](https://github.com/rmaksim/Sublime-Text-2-Image-Viewer)